How to implement SSO on flowable web using azure
I have everything set up on azure for the most part but I don’t see where to initiate SSO on flowable.
I created the app on flowable but I’m not seeing any options at least on my account for implementation of sso.
Not sure where to start because my research lead me to using the terminal.

Please refer- https://documentation.flowable.com/latest/howto/howto/howto-azure-sso-flowable-work

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
